# what is this ets Jan 8 2013,rst cause:4, boot mode:(1,7)

Tags: esp8266

i dont have any idea about this problem. can anyone help me how to fix this?

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h> 
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
const char *ssid = "NUS"; 
const char *password = "s006";
int lo=16.3441;
int la=80.5243;
const char *host = "http://smshorizon.co.in";  
void setup() {
   delay(1000);
   Serial.begin(115200);
   Serial.println("Start");
   WiFi.mode(WIFI_OFF);      
   delay(1000);
   Serial.println("Status");
   WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);   
   Serial.println("Begin...");
   WiFi.begin(ssid, password);  
   Serial.println("");
   Serial.print("Connecting");
   while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
       delay(500);
       Serial.print(".");
    }
   Serial.println("");
   Serial.print("Connected to ");
   Serial.println(ssid);
   Serial.print("IP address: ");

   Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
 }
 void loop() {

  }
```

Sometimes it shows boot mode(1,0)

Comment: Do some further debugging so you can tell us where this error occures. Remove the`WiFi.mode()` lines, those should not be necessary in your case. Another vague guess: add a delay in your loop, I'm not sure if the compiler will do anything dump when there is no loop

Comment: Something else: `163441` is not an `int`. But I don't think that's a problem. It simply doesn't make sense

Comment: the `1` indicates that you have io 15 LOW, io 2 HIGH and io 0 LOW. and the esp8266 starts in flashing mode. pull io 0 up to start the sketch

Comment: reset cause 4 is watchdog reset. your sketch stops so the watchdog resets it